# Multiple inputs for RF/GNSS signal?

Tags: pcb-design, rf, signal-integrity

What are some ways to support multiple connector types for RF signals without impacting signal quality? For instance, if I wanted to support SMA or MHF1/UFL based antenna.

Below is a picture of an example of supporting a chip antenna but also a UFL connector. Can the same be used for UFL and SMA connectors?

[image: Example dual antenna support]

Comment: It sounds like an RF Switch is needed - like CG2214M6-C2 or SKY13585-679LF?